# Strange behaviour of Document Sets in Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

I have found that if I have, for example, three different custom content type Document Sets added to the same library, then, after creating new Document Set and saving it, Details Pane shows additional columns as not filled, but that columns belong to other Document Set content type in the same library.

If I go back to the document library and reopen the same newly created Document Set again, then all columns are displayed correctly.

The same wrong columns are displayed when link to document set is opened from Flow dynamic content called "Link To Item".

I have noticed that CORRECT columns are displayed when URL in browser has "viewid=".

And INCORRECT columns are showed when URL doesn't have "viewid=" - just after saving the document set, or reaching it from MS Teams Dynamic content link.

I have already reported the issue, MS has opened the ticket, but still waiting for an answer.

Also it looks like when I add first custom Document Set content type to Document Library, everything is correct. But when I add second one or third one, and try to create new Set, the additional fields from first content type is show as not filled out.

Answer (score 0):

I create two custom document sets in a document library, each document set has its own custom columns.

When I create two different types of document sets in the library, select one document set, details pane only shows its own custom columns.

I cannot reproduce the issue in my SharePoint Online.

Whether you receive any response from Microsoft?

Comment: To reproduce the issue you have to: Create two Document Set content types - add them to Library - Create one of those Sets - Fill the required Columns - press SAVE - after pressing SAVE you will be REDIRECTED to the newly created Document Set - there you will see the wrong columns.
Also I noticed that when You add first Document Set content type to your library - everything works correct. When you add second Document set content type and create a new Set by it, then it shows wrong columns (adds some columns from the first Set content type).

Comment: As I mentioned wrong columns in those sets are displayed only when redirected to the Document Set after pressing SAVE.
I you will get back to the library and browse those sets - the columns will be displayed correctly.
You can see wrong columns also when you are using Power Automate and for example you are sending a link to the Document Set in email or teams. When you open that link the columns are wrong.

Comment: Until the moment, Microsoft assistant asks to wait for their internal team will answer to that.

Comment: I follow the steps provided above, but I cannot reproduce the issue. Any update from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft confirmed it's a bug. And almost fixed it. At the moment the sets are displayed with correct fields. But another issue appears now. When you press "Edit all", information disappears from all columns. But I will leave it for another post.